# Get multiple HIT submissions or auto-generated answers in MTurk Worker Sandbox

Tags: mechanicalturk

Using MTurk, during testing phase, it might be useful to execute the same HIT multiple times to collect enough data for a WebApplication. However, in the worker's sandbox, only one assignment can be submitted.

Is there a way to get multiple results for the same HIT? E.g. a way to fill in the form multiple times from the same user account, or a method to auto-generate inputs and submit crowd-sourced forms?

Comment: Why not just post the same HIT multiple times?

Comment: Because this makes it cumbersome to process the results of one task. For example, you cannot process all approved assignments of a HIT. Say you want three translations of a text, and then select the best among them. Then you would need to define the same task three times with the same input. Then, you would also need a special form to implement majority voting by collecting the multiple HIT results - and that form would have to be published multiple times again etc.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question. If it's only for testing, it wouldn't seem like that's a problem...you're just trying to make sure the HITs work, right? Obviously that setup on the live server would be problematic, but I thought your question was about small-scale testing in the sandbox.

Comment: Hmm yes it is about more than just verifying that the task can be published. It is about a flow of results that must be processed for one specific HIT, with some assignments being accepted, others being rejected etc.

Comment: This would be particularly useful to test the crowd voting mechanism. Is this possible?